# gRPC C++ difference between function call and gRPC call

Tags: c++, grpc

I'm working my way through the gRPC [Basics Tutorial](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/cpp/basics/) on the gRCP pages and it is is mostly making sense, but there is one portion that I'm stuck on. Near the bottom of the document, at the [Calling service methods](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/cpp/basics/#calling-service-methods) portion, the tutorial goes through how the client calls the simple RPC GetFeature. The relevant code is as follows:

```
void GetFeature() {
  Point point;
  Feature feature;
  point = MakePoint(409146138, -746188906);
  GetOneFeature(point, &feature);
  point = MakePoint(0, 0);
  GetOneFeature(point, &feature);
}

bool GetOneFeature(const Point& point, Feature* feature) {
  ClientContext context;
  Status status = stub_->GetFeature(&context, point, feature);
  ...
}
```

Here is where I"m confused - the client process calls `GetFeature()` with no parameters. This in turn calls `GetOneFeature(Point&, Feature*)` with the Point and Feature parameters...which in turn calls GetFeature() **again**, but this time with three parameters??

Would this not create a never-ending loop? Is it different because it is the client `stub_` calling the `GetFeature()` function? Is that function different from the one defined above?

Answer (score 0):

There are two, unrelated `GetFeature` functions in the snippet. The first one is a free-standing `GetFeature` which does not have any parameters, and is executed by the calling process.

The second `GetFeature` lives in `stub_` class, accepts 3 parameters and marshals calls to the gRPC server. It has nothing in common with the other one, despite having the same name.

Comment: Sergey, thank you for your answer. I see that the `stub_` is defined as `  std::unique_ptr<RouteGuide::Stub> stub_;` - do you know where I could learn more about the `stub_` class and the functions inside of it?

Edit: ...or, I'm thinking that it corresponds to the functions defined in the proto file, and the first function passed in these features called by `stub_` is always the context, and possibly the input and output variables, depending on if it is a single point, or a stream...